# Trying to authenticate a user using two components angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create an efficient authentication in angular using two components: LoginComponent which is responsible for getting the login username and password, and authService which is getting a database of all the users currently exist in the system and authenticates the user who is trying to login. I'm very close to a solution, I know I'm just missing something in the way the credentials are sent between the two components. Here is my code (only the relevant methods):

login.component.ts:

```
  userLogin(credentials:any) {
    this.auth.login(credentials).subscribe(res=> {
      if (res) {
        this.router.navigate(['shopping-cart']);
      } else this.verified=false;
    })
```

auth.service.ts:

```
  login(credentials:any) {

    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/users').pipe(map( res=> {
      this.users = res;
      const exists = this.users.find((a:any)=> {
        
        a.username === credentials.value.username &&
        a.password === credentials.value.password
        return exists;
      });
      console.log(credentials);
      if (exists) {
        localStorage.setItem('token', 'trvgrgrtgrvtrvrtvrvrtvrtvrvrvrvrv');
        localStorage.setItem('username', credentials.value.username);
        return true;
      }
      return false;
 
    }))
```

login.component.html:

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="userLogin(f.value)">
```

Thank You!

Comment: so you stored the token and the userName into localStorage are you asking now how to retrieve these data on other components?

Comment: I know how to do it with local storage but i'm trying to do it without being dependant on it

Answer (score 0):

Never mind,figured it out. the "credentials" simply need to be passed as an object like this: credentials:{username:string,password:string}. Thanks to anyone who was trying to help!